# how can i get the form post value in order to select, when it is multiple in fastselect plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using [fastselect](https://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/) plugin in multiple selection mode.

Dropdown have this value

```
<select class="multipleSelect" multiple name="language[]">
    <option value="1">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="2">Barbados</option>
    <option value="3">Belarus</option>
    <option value="4">Belgium</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Plugin is use like

```
$('.multipleSelect').fastselect();
```

When i select => 2,3,1,4 then it will like

```
<select class="multipleSelect" multiple name="language[]">
        <option selected value="1">Bangladesh</option>
        <option selected value="2">Barbados</option>
        <option selected value="3">Belarus</option>
        <option selected value="4">Belgium</option>
        ...
    </select>
```

Whwn i post this form it will give me **language[ ]** array always => 1,2,3,4

i need **language[ ]** array in selection mode => 2,3,1,4 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your code here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: hi, Upendra joshi, i wrote the code same as plugin syntax. can u see in this in above fast select link

Comment: @RajanPrajapati You want in sequence of select data ?

Comment: Yeah , @hack it

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.multipleSelect').fastselect();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/dbrekalo/fastselect/master/dist/fastselect.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dbrekalo/fastsearch/master/dist/fastsearch.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dbrekalo/fastselect/master/dist/fastselect.min.js"></script>

<form name="myform" method="post">
<select class="multipleSelect" multiple name="language">
    <option value="1">Apple </option>
    <option value="2">Orange </option>
    <option value="3">Mango </option>
 
</select>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<button name="submit" name="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Comment: @RajanPrajapati Ok Got it can you give me some time